# Hover state not working CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do one of the most basic things in CSS. A hover state for one of my buttons, but for some reason, it's not doing anything! What is going on with it?

Task info

```
<label>Your Note:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="noteTitle" placeholder="Note Title..."><br/>
        <textarea id="note" placeholder="Add Content..."></textarea> <br/>
      <button onclick="createNote()" class="btnStyle">Create Task</button>



<br/> <br/>
<label>Note Id:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="noteId" placeholder="Type Note Id..."> <br/>
<div class="align"><button onclick="deleteNote()" class="btnStyle">Delete Task</button></div>

    <div id="noteTitlesId"></div>

        <div class="align"><button onclick="getNoteTitles()" class="btnStyle">Get Task Titles</button></div>
        <div class="align"> <button onclick="updateNote()" class="btnStyle">Update note</button></div>

        </div>
```

My CSS for it:

```
 .btnStyle {
    border: 0.5px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
}



.btnStyle :hover {
    background-color: #eb9356;
    color: #ffff;
}
```

Comment: Drop the space.. `.btnStyle:hover`

Comment: Can't believe it worked. Can't believe I missed that. You are a life saver.

Comment: So you know exactly what you have done, leaving a space then a selector. turns the second selector to `descendant of`. Effectively what you have is when a defendant od `btnStyle` is hovered, apply this style to the descendant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Give space between **.btnStyle :hover** remove that one space and code for that is below:

```
.btnStyle:hover {
}
```